# automatically formatting the Calendar Object into receiver timezone

Tags: java

I have problem in formatting the `Calendar Object` into the receiver's timezone system while marshaling the `Calendar Object`. `Calendar Object` is formatted to receiver based on receiver timezone.

Eingansnachricht:
`< CreDtTm > 2017-09-28T11:22:29.000+08:00 </ CreDtTm >`
Ausgangsnachricht:
`< CreDtTm > 2017-09-28T05:22:29.000+02:00 </ CreDtTm >`

Comment: Could you append example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer and that solution resolved my problem. datetime is Calendar Object.

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone(datetime.getTimeZone());
    final String formattedDatetime = dateTimeFormat.format(datetime.getTime());
        final String zone = datetime.getTimeZone().getID().substring(3);
        if (zone.contains(":") && zone.length() == 6) {
            return formattedDatetime.concat(zone);
        }
        return formattedDatetime;
    }    
}
```